# Can We get sum of list attributes in oracle without loop?

Tags: json, oracle, plsql, oracle12c

can we get the sum of all hours in the below list? I am using the sum function with JSON_QUERY function but getting error.

```
 SET SERVEROUT ON
    
    DECLARE 
    data    varchar2(200);
    JSONSTRING  VARCHAR2(4000):= ' {"Implement_Details": [
        {
          "Hours": "100",
          "Implement1": "Laser Leveler"
        },
        {
          "Hours": "400",
          "Implement1": "Trolley"
        },
        {
          "Hours": "100",
          "Implement1": "Cultivator"
        }
      ]}';
      
      BEGIN 
      
      SELECT SUM(JSON_QUERY(JSONSTRING, '$.Implement_Details[*].Hours' WITH ARRAY WRAPPER)) INTO DATA
                FROM dual;
    
      
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(data);
    
    end;
```

expected output:
`100 + 400 + 100 = 600`

> Error report - **ORA-01722**: invalid number **ORA-06512**: at line 20
> 01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"
> *Cause:    The specified number was invalid.
> *Action:   Specify a valid number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use `SUM()` on the whole ARRAY.
What I did was I turned the `Hours` into a table and used the `SUM()` on the column, how you normally would in a `SELECT` clause.

```
SET SERVEROUT ON

DECLARE 
    data    varchar2(200);
    JSONSTRING  VARCHAR2(4000):= ' {"Implement_Details": [
        {
          "Hours": 100,
          "Implement1": "Laser Leveler"
        },
        {
          "Hours": 400,
          "Implement1": "Trolley"
        },
        {
          "Hours": 100,
          "Implement1": "Cultivator"
        }
      ]}';
      
      BEGIN 
      
        SELECT SUM(value) INTO DATA
          FROM JSON_TABLE((JSON_QUERY(JSONSTRING, '$.Implement_Details[*].Hours' WITH ARRAY WRAPPER)), '$[*]' COLUMNS (value PATH '$'));    
      
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(data);
    
    end;
```